# flickering Translate animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I have a HorizontalScrollView with a LinearLayout in it. The Linerlayout has images in it. When i use TranslateAnimation to move the image from one x-coordinate to another x coordinate. the animation is very flickring. The image size is around 2400 pix wide and 100 pix height.

I can't find a way to prevent the filckring with TranslateAnimation. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you testing this on the emulator or a real device?  The emulator can be pretty jerky sometimes.

Comment: please make this a comment for the next time, its not question for more information and not an answer. thanks

Comment: I'm still in a padded room here, being a SO noob, so I didn't have the option to leave a comment.  Your point is well taken and I will do so in the future when the SO gods give me the option (maybe after I earn more rep?) :)

Comment: Looked like answer to me -- he pointed OP to a possible solution